# C# / WPF - BindingList<T> containing and maintaining the contents of a HashSet<BindingList<T>>

Tags: c#, wpf, bindinglist

I want a master `BindingList<T>` which contains a reference to all the items in child lists and

Does this already exist or should I create one? I guess it would be an `AggregatedBindingList<T>` which would have a constructor;

```
public AggregatedBindingList<T>(IEnumerable<BindingList<T> items)
```

And methods;

```
public bool AddBindingList(BindingList<T> list);
public bool RemoveBindingList(BindingList<T> list);
```

Where I'd hook into the Add/Remove/Clear change events and update the master accordingly.

My data structure is not too dissimilar to the below if we imagine each as a BindingList (the count is displayed) and Inhabitants are only added to the leaf lists but I want to maintain the root correctly.

```
GB - 1050
       |- England  - 230
       |- Wales    - 200
       |- Scotland - 620
```

I'm sure I can write something but this must have been done before, no?